# Calculating an expression on python with variable subsitution

Tags: python, expression, sympy

I'm self learning Python's SymPy and am stuck. I have an expression `f = x**3-7*x+7` and I need to calculate `f(1/x+1)`.

I tried

```
x = symbols('x')
f = x**3-7*x+7
f_new = f.subs(x, (1/(x+1)))
simplify(f_new)
```

The result is `x/(x+1)**4+7-7/(x+1)+(x+1)**(-4)`. But I need to get the coeffs of `f_new`. Even trying `evalf` and `eval` does not seem to work.
I understand that it "locks" `x+1` as the new `x`, so it doesn't make the right calculations.

Is there another way to evaluate an expression `f(x)` with the form of `x=1/x+1`?

Comment: Could you please clarify what coeffs do you want to get? It's not a polynomial after substitution.

Comment: `cancel()` will take a rational function and write as `p/q` where `p` and `q` are expanded polynomials with no common factors. It's the simplest way to put a rational function into canonical form.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the expression as a fraction, and then get the coefficients of numerator and denominator:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
f = x**3-7*x+7
f_new = f.subs(x, (1/(x+1)))
numerator, denominator = fraction(together(f_new))

print(numerator)
print(denominator)

print(Poly(numerator).coeffs())
print(Poly(denominator).coeffs())
```

Output:

```
7*(x + 1)**3 - 7*(x + 1)**2 + 1
(x + 1)**3
[7, 14, 7, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
```

Use `all_coeffs` instead of `coeffs` when also zero-coefficients are needed.

Use `numerator = expand(numerator)` if you just want to write the polynomial in its expanded form.

I tried with `simplify(f_new).as_numer_denom()`, but that approach leaves a superfluous `(x + 1)**2` factor in both numerator and denominator.

PS: As mentioned in the comments by @asmeurer, you can use `cancel` to write the fraction in its canonical form.